# how to do: what i pick on combobox1 will show on combobox2?

Tags: c#

how to do: what i pick on combobox1 will show on combobox2 ?

is it possible ?  (in C#)

thank's in advance

Comment: Could u plz elaborate your Question more clearly. Does it mean: what u select from combobox1 should get selected automatically on combobox2. If so is it necessary that both control contains same item.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to subscride second combobox on the SelectedIndexChanged event of the first combobox and change value when event triggers. Also you need to make sure that both combobox have several items or you will need to add missing items to second combobox dynamically.

Event handler example:

```
    private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        object selectedValue = this.comboBox1.SelectedValue;
        this.comboBox2.SelectedValue = selectedValue;
    }
```

Comment: thank's for the help, the 2 combo's are connect to same database. can i get a sample code for this ?